# Replace string after a given string in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, file, replace

Here is my file :

```
[Server]
port_nb = 2222
dist_user = martin
dist_ip = 192.168.11.111

[Client]
local_port = 22
```

I want to replace with Powershell the string after a given string by a var in my code.

**I don't want to use** `((Get-Content -path ssh_config.cfg -Raw) -replace '2222','2589'`
**because I hardcoded 2222 and this value can change randomly**, so I can't perform a search on a value after `=` and then replace it.

That's why I think I have to search for `port_nb =` first and then replace the string which can be found after it.

To be clear, I want to change the thing after `port_nb =` for exemple by what I want.

How can I achieve that ? By Index maybe but I don't find how to use replace by using Index...
Thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a regex pattern instead of your hard-coded '2222':

```
(Get-Content -Path ssh_config.cfg -Raw) -replace "port_nb = \d+", "port_nb = 2589"
```

Comment: That's perfect, never thought about it...Thx :) !

Comment: Maybe more save considering that spaces are not always in place: (Get-Content -Path ssh_config.cfg -Raw) -replace "port_nb *= *\d+", "port_nb = 2589"